# Get value of UILabel at coordinate (x,y) in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, coordinates

I am looking for a way to find the value(text) of a UILabel at a given (x,y) coordinate.

All other questions seem to be about getting the (x,y) of a label, I am trying to do the opposite...

For example (30,40) would return the value of the Label at that location.

Thank you!

**Update**

```
func getLabel(location: CGPoint){

  let view = self.view.hitTest(location, withEvent:nil)
  //I would like to get the value of the label here but I'm not sure how to. 

}

@IBAction func tap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    var coordinate = sender.locationInView(GraphView?())
    getLabel(coordinate)
}
```

Comment: Instead of working with co-ordinates, why don't you use tag?

Comment: Look at the UIView documentation under the heading "Hit Testing in a View".  Depending on whether all your sub-views are labels or not, you can either use `hitTest:withEvent:` or `pointInside:withEvent:`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this by [hit-testing](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/event_delivery_responder_chain/event_delivery_responder_chain.html).

Pass the point you want to the top-level view, and it will return the deepest view within the view hierarchy that contains that point.

```
UIView *view = [self.view hitTest:location withEvent:nil];
```

In Swift, it would look like

```
let selectedView = view.hitTest(location, withEvent: nil)
```

**Update:**

You need to set the label's `userInteractionEnabled` to true for your labels to register the hit.

You'll need to check the returned view to see if it is a label, then check to see if it has any text.

```
if let label = selectedView as? UILabel
{
    if label.text!
    {
        // .. do what you want with the label's text
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Can you perhaps tell me how the Swift syntax would look? I am not familiar with obj-c.

Comment: `@IBAction func tap(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        var coordinate = sender.locationInView(GraphView?())
        getLabel(coordinate)
    } 
    func getLabel(location: CGPoint){
        
        let view = self.view.hitTest(location, withEvent:nil)
        
        println(view)
        println(view.text)
        
    }` could you help out?

Comment: You can edit your question to update it by adding the code you have tried.  Please also mention the problem you are having with the code, to help other readers of the question.

Comment: Thank you for the guidance!